# Passing File Path throught URI Protocol launch application

Tags: powershell, web

I have URI Protocol set up like this

```
Key Name:          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testap
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   31/10/2018 - 11:32 AM
Value 0
  Name:            URL protocol
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            

Key Name:          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testap\shell
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   31/10/2018 - 11:27 AM

Key Name:          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testap\shell\open
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   31/10/2018 - 11:27 AM

Key Name:          HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testap\shell\open\command
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   31/10/2018 - 11:37 AM
Value 0
  Name:            <NO NAME>
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            "E:\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

I want to pass a file path like this `"E:\ShortHelp_English.pdf"`

When I run `testap:E:/ShortHelp_English.pdf`

My application return an Error like this

[image]

Can anyone show me the right way of passing my file path to the application ?

Comment: Perhaps if you try with a backslash: `testap:E:\ShortHelp_English.pdf`

Comment: *Your* application returns the error? What is the value of the argument that is passed to your app? I assume it's more than the path.

Comment: i am doing web broswer lauch application (ABBYFinder) and getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but keep in mind that the **full url** (incl schema) is passed to your application:

> testap:E:/ShortHelp_English.pdf

So what you might want to do is something like

```
if (path.StartsWith("testapp:")) {
    path = path.Substring(8);
}
```

or

```
path = new Uri(path).AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: i am doing web broswer lauch application (ABBYFinder) and getting this error